# Проблема с Sortables

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
  deactivate: function( event, ui ) {
      $(ui.item).animate({width: "auto"}, 650)
  },
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
      $(ui.item).animate({width: "160"}, 650)
  },
  connectWith: ".column"
});
```

Работает, но почему-то не возвращает width: "auto", если поставить число - то все нормально. В чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

[Animate Height/Width to “Auto”](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/)